# regular expression to allow only specific numbers

Tags: asp.net, regex

I am looking to have a regular expression that allows only specific numbers to be entered, e.g. 2,4,5,6,10,18

I tried something like

```
"'2'|'4'|'5'|'6'|'10'|'18'"
```

and anything that i typed failed the regex and then the computer pointed its finger at me and laughed.

where am i going wrong?

Comment: You don't need the single quotes. In addition, you should put `^(` at the beginning and `)$` at the end if you want to match the entire string.

Comment: I am Not really good at RegEx but I use this [link for my testing](http://regexhero.net/tester/). Might be useful to you to debug the issue sooner.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The single quotes are unnecessary. The regex you are looking for is: `^(2|4|5|6|10|18)$`.

The symbols `^` and `$` denote the start and the end of the line, to prevent `121` from matching (since it contains `2`).

Comment: I dont know why the same thing i have implemented but not working. Do i need to add more properties like EnableClientScript of regular expression in asp.net?

Comment: @ArulManivannan: Your problem probably lies somewhere else. Please create a [mcve] and start a new question on that.