# How to allow input field numbers 1, 2, or 3 to be entered

Tags: javascript, html

I have a HTML5 input form, which needs to accept only the numbers 1, 2, or 3.
This is not just allowing min/max for validation.
The form field should not allow invalid characters to be entered.

So far I have this below, and it works, but with any number.
Also, the input must not allow numbers such as 11, 12, 13, 21, 22, 23, 31, 32222, etc.

```
<input
  type="number"
  id="endLegDarts"
  class="form-control"
  min="1"
  max="3"
  maxlength="1"
  aria-describedby="endDartsHelp"
  oninput="this.value = this.value.replace(/[^0-9.]/g, '').replace(/(\..*)\./g, '$1');"
  required="required"
/>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [regular expression to allow only specific numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9071001/regular-expression-to-allow-only-specific-numbers)

Comment: I don't think so, when I use this, it allows any number to be entered except for 1, 2, or three to begin, but will allow 4332211
oninput="this.value = this.value.replace(/^(1|2|3)$/, '');"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do it with a simple html5 input field with a `pattern="[1-3]"` attribute:

```css
input:invalid {
  border: red solid 3px;
}
```

```html
<input
  type="text"
  name="endLegDarts"
  pattern="[1-3]"
/>
```

OK, this one will only allow the single characters "1","2" or "3" to be entered:

```html
<input type="number" name="endLegDarts" placeholder="please enter 1, 2 or 3" oninput="this.value=this.value.match(/[1-3]/)">
```

Comment: Carsten, this will allow only validation, not limit what can be entered, as mentioned "The form field should not allow invalid characters to be entered".

Answer (score 0):

You should try using div instead of input
like this: (type in this snippet to see)

```js
var x = document.getElementById("my-input")
        window.onkeyup = function(e){
            e = e || window.event;
            if(e.keyCode === 49){ //keycode for 1
                x.innerHTML = "1"
            }
            else if(e.keyCode == 50){ //keycode for 2
                x.innerHTML = "2"
            }
            else if(e.keyCode == 51){ //keycode for 3
                x.innerHTML = "3"
            }
        }
```

```html
<span>type here</span>
    <div id="my-input"></div>
```

Comment: What is the benefit of using a div over a form input?